# What is the "type" of a generic IList<T>?

Tags: c#, list, generics

Imagine an extension like this..

```
public static Blah<T>(this IList<T> ra)
 {
 ..
 }
```

Imagine you want to make a note of the most recently-called one.

```
private static IList recent;
public static Blah<T>(this IList<T> ra)
 {
 recent = ra;
 ..
 }
```

You actually can not do that:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>` to `System.Collections.IList`.

1- You can simply make `recent` an `object` and that seems to work fine, but it seems like a poor solution.

2- It seems if you do have recent as an `IList`, you can actually cast the "ra" to that...

```
recent = (System.Collections.IList)ra;
```

and it seems to work. Seems strange though??  So,

3- Actually, **what type should recent *be*** so that you don't have to cast to it?? How can you make `recent` the same type as `ra`? You can't say this ....

```
private static System.Collections.Generic.IList recent;
```

it's not meaningful.  So what the heck is the type of "ra"?  What should `recent` "be" so that you can simply say `recent=ra` ?

(I mention this is for Unity, since you constantly use generic extensions in Unity.)

---

4- Consider a a further difficulty the case if you want to have a Dictionary of them all.

```
private static Dictionary<object,int> recents = new Dictionary<object,int>();
```

I can really only see how to do it as an object.

---

## USE CASE EXAMPLE.

Here's an extension you use constantly, everywhere, in game engineering,

```
public static T AnyOne<T>(this IList<T> ra)
    {
    int k = ra.Count;
    if (k<=0) {Debug.Log("Warn!"+k);}
    int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,k);
    return ra[r];
    }
```

no problem so far. So,

```
explosions.AnyOne();
yetAnotherEnemyToDefeat = dinosaurStyles.AnyOne();
```

and so on.  However.  Of course, actual random selections feel bad; in practice what you want is a *fairly non-repeating order, more like a shuffle*. Usually the best thing to do with any list or array is shuffle them, and serve them in that order; perhaps shuffle again each time through.  Simple example, you have 20 random sound effects `roars` , being for when the dino roars.  Each time you need one, if you do this

```
 roars.AnyOne();
```

its OK, but not great. It will sound sort of suck.  (Most players will report it as "not being random" or "repeating a lot".) This

```
 roars.NextOne();
```

is much better.  So, `NextOne()` should, on its own, (a) if we're at the start shuffle the list, (b) serve it in that order, (c) perhaps shuffle it again each time you use up the list.  {There are further subtleties, eg, try not to repeat any near the end/start of the reshuffle, but irrelevant here.}

Note that subclassing List (and/or array) would suck for many obvious reasons, it's a job for a simple self-contained extension.

So then, here's a beautiful way to implement `NextOne()` using a simple stateful extension.

```
private static Dictionary<object,int> nextOne = new Dictionary<object,int>();
public static T NextOne<T>(this IList<T> ra)
    {
    if ( ! nextOne.ContainsKey(ra) )
        // i.e., we've never heard about this "ra" before
        nextOne.Add(ra,0);
    
    int index = nextOne[ra];
    
    // time to shuffle?
    if (index==0)
        {
        Debug.Log("shuffling!"); // be careful to mutate, don't change the ra!
        IList<T> temp = ra.OrderBy(r => UnityEngine.Random.value).ToList();
        ra.Clear(); foreach(T t in temp) ra.Add(t);
        }
    
    T result = ra[index];
    ++index;
    index=index%ra.Count;
    nextOne[ra] = index;
    return result;
    }
```

This is surely the perfect example of a "stateful extension".

Notice indeed, I just used "object".

I guess in a way, the fundamental question in this QA is, **is it best to use the Dictionary of "object" there, or, would something else more typey be better?**  Really that's the question at hand. Cheers!

Comment: Having a static method that keeps static state seems really bad to me. I would look into other solutions that doesn't involve that.

Comment: `IList<T>`  and`IList<U>` are not the same type so you cannot have a  single variable that is both, since a variable has only one type.

Comment: Hi Jeff - you're saying you don't like the idea of extensions that are stateful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a single globally most recent `IList<T>` where `T` potentially varies each time, then your only options are to use `object` or `dynamic`. Both require casting; the latter just casts automatically.

I think your confusion stems from thinking that `IList<T>` inherits `IList` - [it doesn't](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

So arguably you *could* do this, although I don't see any advantage really:

```
private static IEnumerable recent;
public static void Blah<T>(this IList<T> ra)
{
    recent = ra;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it; I guess Im struggling to see why I can't do this `System.Collections.Generic.IList recent`.  After all, "ra" is a `System.Collections.Generic.IList`  Why can't I just make a variable which is a `System.Collections.Generic.IList recent` ... I guess I don't understand that.  :O

Comment: Indeed: do you think there's any problem just casting ra down to `(System.Collections.IList)ra` ?  tricky one...

Comment: @JoeBlow Just added a little more to clarify.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm curious: why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Ahh ... that does explain it I guess.  Thanks.  (Why do ... it's just a stateful extension, an extension with memory.)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, and most type-safe, solution is to store a separate value for each `T`:

```
private static class RecentHolder<T> {
    public static IList<T> Value { get; set; }
}
public static Blah<T>(this IList<T> ra) {
    RecentHolder<T>.Value = ra;
}
```

Comment: But then there will be a "most recent" per type, not globally.

Comment: Also I really want to know the answer to my question (3) - heh!  What the hell type is it?  There must be some type where you can say `x = ra;`  (other than just `object`.)

Comment: @JoeBlow: Not really.  In the absence of a separate common non-generic base class, the only common type between `IBlah<X>` and `IBlah<Y>` is `object`.  OTOH, `IList<T>` happens to implement the non-generic `IEnumerable`, so there is that.  Had it been covariant (eg, `IReadOnlyList<T>`), there would also be `IReadOnlyList<object>`.

Comment: Type safe, but not thread safe.  Might be an important issue depending on the code.  (Really goes for all static methods/fields.. answers here so far, not that SLaks's is the only one with this issue).

Answer (score 2):

> What is the “type” of a generic IList< T >?

The base type..

```
Console.WriteLine( new List<int>().GetType().BaseType);
```

> System.Object

The Generic Type definition ...

```
Console.WriteLine( new List<int>().GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition());
```

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]

And to expand on [SLAKS Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36243402/209259)

> Not really. In the absence of a separate common non-generic base class

You can also use interfaces.  So you could do...

```
public interface IName
{
  string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Person : IName
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Dog : IName
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could

```
private static List<IName> recent;
public static Blah<T>(this List<IName> ra)
{
  recent = ra;
  ..
}
```

and it won't matter if you put `Dog` or `Person` in the list.

**OR**

I can't believe I didn't think about this last night; LINQ to the rescue using `object`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;                   

public class Program
{
    private static class WonkyCache
    {
        private static List<object> cache = new List<object>();
        
        public static void Add(object myItem)
        {
            cache.Add(myItem);
        }
        
        public static IEnumerable<T> Get<T>()
        {
            var result = cache.OfType<T>().ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        WonkyCache.Add(1);
        WonkyCache.Add(2);
        WonkyCache.Add(3);
        WonkyCache.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        WonkyCache.Add("George");
        WonkyCache.Add("Abraham");
        
        var numbers = WonkyCache.Get<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(numbers.GetType());           

        foreach(var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
        
        var strings = WonkyCache.Get<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(strings.GetType());
        
        foreach(var s in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
>
> George
>
> Abraham

Try:

```
public static class StatefulRandomizer<T>
    // Use IEquatable<T> for Intersect()
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    // this could be enhanced to be a percentage 
    // of elements instead of hardcoded
    private static Stack<T> _memory = new Stack<T>();
    private static IEnumerable<T> _cache;

    public static void UpdateWith(IEnumerable<T> newCache)
    {
        _cache = newCache.ToList();

        // Setup the stack again, keep only ones that match
        var matching = _memory.Intersect(newCache);
        _memory = new Stack<T>(matching);
    }

    public static T GetNextNonRepeatingRandom()
    {
        var nonrepeaters = _cache
            .Except(_memory);

        // Not familar with unity.. but this should make 
        // sense what I am doing
        var next = nonrepeaters.ElementAt(UnityEngine.Random(0, nonrepeaters.Count()-1));

        // this fast, Stack will know it's count so no GetEnumerator()
        // and _cache List is the same (Count() will call List.Count)
        if (_memory.Count > _cache.Count() / 2)
        {
            _memory.Pop();
        }

        _memory.Push(next);

        return next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that my brain is clear, the extra solution at the bottom might be of great use.

Comment: I read your example, and what you're trying really makes this a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  It seems what your trying to do is take a list of *known* T, I say known, because the consumer knows they are *roars* get an a 'random one'.  SLaks answer in this case really does solve the problem, I'll just add the random part in an update...

Comment: Hi Erik!  nah, in the example of "roars".  it could be almost anything. in a typical game you would use NextOne (or indeed AnyOne) on either lists or arrays of almost anything .. strings, Sprites, animations, meshes, weird stuff like delegates, audio etc etc.  (Unless I misunderstand you.)

Comment: @JoeBlow Hey join this chat if you have a minute http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107496/what-is-the-type-of-a-generic-ilistt